# How get steam nickname via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, steam-web-api

Hello i now using this php code for get steam nicknames

```
function EchoPlayerName($steamid){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");//link to user xml
    if(!empty($xml)) {
        $username = $xml->steamID;
        echo $username;
    }
}
```

or

```
$steam = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={API_KEY}&steamids=$steamid64", true);
$steamarray = json_decode($steam, true);
$name = $steamarray['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
```

but i this using for listing players and loading page is slow
so i want this data load via javascript after full load page

any ideas?

API example

```
{"response":{"players":[{"steamid":"76561197964477177","communityvisibilitystate":3,"profilestate":1,"personaname":"The [G]amerX #.","lastlogoff":1558765863,"commentpermission":1,"profileurl":"https://steamcommunity.com/id/gamerxcz/","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/6673d6df066386d232164e8f9a5d9b36cad1d013.jpg","avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/6673d6df066386d232164e8f9a5d9b36cad1d013_medium.jpg","avatarfull":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/66/6673d6df066386d232164e8f9a5d9b36cad1d013_full.jpg","personastate":0,"realname":"Community Owner","primaryclanid":"103582791433644720","timecreated":1076786008,"personastateflags":0,"loccountrycode":"CZ"}]}}
```

Comment: Could you please share the response of web service?

Comment: web page normal load but slow

Comment: I want API response which you are calling that to parse it.

Comment: added in post if that's what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should get Data using ajax of pure javascript or jquery. Then you should target an HTML element that you want to fill it using this retrieved data. Imagine element with ID `target`.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={API_KEY}&steamids=$steamid64",
    }).done(function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#target').text(json['response']['players'][0]['personaname']);
    });
});
```

pure javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key={API_KEY}&steamids=$steamid64');
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = json['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
        } else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Remember to place these scripts at the end of your document.